# Minifilter driver not blocking file edition

Tags: c++, minifilter

I am trying to create a File System Filter (Minifilter) driver. For that I am following the tutorial provided here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ukUf3kSSTOU

In a brief way, in the tutorial you create a minifilter driver that stops you from writing into a file called OPENME.txt.

This is the code I have:

```
#include <fltKernel.h>
#include <dontuse.h>
#include <suppress.h>

PFLT_FILTER FilterHandle = NULL;
NTSTATUS MiniUnload(FLT_FILTER_UNLOAD_FLAGS Flags);
FLT_POSTOP_CALLBACK_STATUS MiniPostCreate(PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data, PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects, PVOID* CompletionContec, FLT_POST_OPERATION_FLAGS Flags);
FLT_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS MiniPreCreate(PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data, PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects, PVOID* CompletionContec);
FLT_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS MiniPreWrite(PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data, PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects, PVOID* CompletionContec);

const FLT_OPERATION_REGISTRATION Callbacks[] =
{
    { IRP_MJ_CREATE,0,MiniPreCreate, MiniPostCreate },
    { IRP_MJ_WRITE,0,MiniPreWrite, NULL },
    { IRP_MJ_OPERATION_END }
};

const FLT_REGISTRATION FilterRegistration =
{
    sizeof(FLT_REGISTRATION),
    FLT_REGISTRATION_VERSION,
    0,
    NULL,
    Callbacks,
    MiniUnload,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL
};

NTSTATUS MiniUnload(FLT_FILTER_UNLOAD_FLAGS Flags)
{
    KdPrint(("driver unload \r\n"));
    FltUnregisterFilter(FilterHandle);

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

FLT_POSTOP_CALLBACK_STATUS MiniPostCreate(PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data, PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects, PVOID* CompletionContec, FLT_POST_OPERATION_FLAGS Flags)
{
    KdPrint(("post create running \r\n"));

    return FLT_POSTOP_FINISHED_PROCESSING;
}

FLT_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS MiniPreCreate(PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data, PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects, PVOID* CompletionContec)
{
    PFLT_FILE_NAME_INFORMATION FileNameInfo;
    NTSTATUS status;
    WCHAR Name[200] = { 0 };

    status = FltGetFileNameInformation(Data, FLT_FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED | FLT_FILE_NAME_QUERY_DEFAULT, &FileNameInfo);

    if (NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        status = FltParseFileNameInformation(FileNameInfo);

        if (NT_SUCCESS(status))
        {
            if (FileNameInfo->Name.MaximumLength < 260)
            {
                RtlCopyMemory(Name, FileNameInfo->Name.Buffer, FileNameInfo->Name.MaximumLength);

                KdPrint(("create file: %wa \r\n", Name));
            }
        }

        FltReleaseFileNameInformation(FileNameInfo);
    }

    return FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_WITH_CALLBACK;
}

FLT_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS MiniPreWrite(PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data, PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects, PVOID* CompletionContec)
{
    PFLT_FILE_NAME_INFORMATION FileNameInfo;
    NTSTATUS status;
    WCHAR Name[200] = { 0 };

    status = FltGetFileNameInformation(Data, FLT_FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED | FLT_FILE_NAME_QUERY_DEFAULT, &FileNameInfo);

    if (NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        status = FltParseFileNameInformation(FileNameInfo);

        if (NT_SUCCESS(status))
        {
            if (FileNameInfo->Name.MaximumLength < 260)
            {
                RtlCopyMemory(Name, FileNameInfo->Name.Buffer, FileNameInfo->Name.MaximumLength);

                _wcsupr(Name);

                if (wcsstr(Name, L"OPENME.txt") != NULL)
                {
                    KdPrint(("write file %ws blocked \r\n", Name));

                    Data->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER;
                    Data->IoStatus.Information = 0;

                    FltReleaseFileNameInformation(FileNameInfo);

                    return FLT_PREOP_COMPLETE;
                }

                KdPrint(("create file: %wa \r\n", Name));
            }
        }

        FltReleaseFileNameInformation(FileNameInfo);
    }

    return FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_NO_CALLBACK;
}

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath)
{
    NTSTATUS status;

    status = FltRegisterFilter(DriverObject, &FilterRegistration, &FilterHandle);

    if (NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        status = FltStartFiltering(FilterHandle);

        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
        {
            FltUnregisterFilter(FilterHandle);
        }
    }

    return status;
}
```

and

```
;;;
;;; FsFilter2
;;;

[Version]
Signature   = "$Windows NT$"
; TODO - Change the Class and ClassGuid to match the Load Order Group value, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg462963
; Class       = "ActivityMonitor"                         ;This is determined by the work this filter driver does
; ClassGuid   = {b86dff51-a31e-4bac-b3cf-e8cfe75c9fc2}    ;This value is determined by the Load Order Group value
Class = "ActivityMonitor"
ClassGuid = {b86dff51-a31e-4bac-b3cf-e8cfe75c9fc2}
Provider    = %ManufacturerName%
DriverVer = 01/26/2018,16.49.59.238
CatalogFile = FsFilter2.cat

[DestinationDirs]
DefaultDestDir          = 12
MiniFilter.DriverFiles  = 12            ;%windir%\system32\drivers

;;
;; Default install sections
;;

[DefaultInstall]
OptionDesc          = %ServiceDescription%
CopyFiles           = MiniFilter.DriverFiles

[DefaultInstall.Services]
AddService          = %ServiceName%,,MiniFilter.Service

;;
;; Default uninstall sections
;;

[DefaultUninstall]
DelFiles   = MiniFilter.DriverFiles

[DefaultUninstall.Services]
DelService = %ServiceName%,0x200      ;Ensure service is stopped before deleting

;
; Services Section
;

[MiniFilter.Service]
DisplayName      = %ServiceName%
Description      = %ServiceDescription%
ServiceBinary    = %12%\%DriverName%.sys        ;%windir%\system32\drivers\
Dependencies     = "FltMgr"
ServiceType      = 2                            ;SERVICE_FILE_SYSTEM_DRIVER
StartType        = 3                            ;SERVICE_DEMAND_START
ErrorControl     = 1                            ;SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL
; TODO - Change the Load Order Group value
; LoadOrderGroup = "FSFilter Activity Monitor"
LoadOrderGroup = "FSFilter Activity Monitor"
AddReg           = MiniFilter.AddRegistry

;
; Registry Modifications
;

[MiniFilter.AddRegistry]
HKR,,"DebugFlags",0x00010001 ,0x0
HKR,,"SupportedFeatures",0x00010001,0x3
HKR,"Instances","DefaultInstance",0x00000000,%DefaultInstance%
HKR,"Instances\"%Instance1.Name%,"Altitude",0x00000000,%Instance1.Altitude%
HKR,"Instances\"%Instance1.Name%,"Flags",0x00010001,%Instance1.Flags%

;
; Copy Files
;

[MiniFilter.DriverFiles]
%DriverName%.sys

[SourceDisksFiles]
FsFilter2.sys = 1,,

[SourceDisksNames]
1 = %DiskId1%,,,

;;
;; String Section
;;

[Strings]
; TODO - Add your manufacturer
ManufacturerName        = "Template"
ServiceDescription      = "FsFilter2 Mini-Filter Driver"
ServiceName             = "FsFilter2"
DriverName              = "FsFilter2"
DiskId1                 = "FsFilter2 Device Installation Disk"

;Instances specific information.
DefaultInstance         = "FsFilter2 Instance"
Instance1.Name          = "FsFilter2 Instance"
; TODO - Change the altitude value, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/drivers/ifs/load-order-groups-and-altitudes-for-minifilter-drivers
Instance1.Altitude       = "371000"
Instance1.Flags         = 0x0              ; Allow all attachments
```

Then, in the project properties I set the following configurations:

- Plataform: x64
- C/C++ > Warning Level: Level1 (/W1)
- Linker > Treat Linker Warning As Errors: No (/WX:NO)
- Driver Settings > Target OS Version: Windows 10 or higher
- Driver Settings > Target Plataform: Desktop

Then, I build the application, and I get the successful message, with the .inf and .sys files created.

My target machine is Windows 10 x64, and I already have set the option to allow to use drivers not signed.

I run the following command:

> pnputil /add-driver FsFilter2.inf

And the driver is successful installed. I get the output:

```
Microsoft PnP Utility

Adding driver package:  FsFilter2.inf 
Driver package added successfully.
Published Name:         oem73.inf

Total driver packages:  1 
Added driver packages:  1
```

Then, I start the drive by doing:

> net start FsFilter2

And get the following output:

```
The FsFilter2 service was started successfully.
```

Yet, I can still write into the OPENME.txt file... while in the tutorial its not possible...

I am also using DebugView and can't see any of my messages in it...

Does anyone knows what am I doing wrong? or what can I do to find out my problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I certainly hope the Youtube video did not teach you to do things this way.
There many many mistakes here, so many that I would first of all suggest you go and check out the Microsoft minifilter samples.
They are situated [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/filesys/miniFilter)
More specifically I would suggest you check out the scanner sample, or avscan, but the latter is a bit more complicated.
In short here are a few suggestions:

1. Make your check in post-create not pre-create since the file object is not yet opened by the file-system below you and thus the FltGetFileNameInformation will itself do a FltCreateFile to open the file in order to query the name
2. In PostCreate also decide if you want to allow this file to be opened. You should check the DesiredAccess that the open is done with and if it fits your mask, in this case a **FILE_GENERIC_WRITE** the simply deny the create. See [with what API to cancel a file open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/fltkernel/nf-fltkernel-fltcancelfileopen) and [where the desired access is located](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544687%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
3. Don't forget to set the Data->IoStatus.Status to **STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED** since **STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER** is pretty ambiguous and it is not the case.
4. Do not do any processing in the PreWrite for this as it is no, need you already have blocked the Create.
5. Don't use unsafe string functions like wcsstr, maybe consider using API that are available in **ntstrsafe.h** and they do bounds check based on the provided length rather than assuming a NULL character at the end.

Good luck, and hope this helps.

Comment: I decided to follow your advice and started from scratch, following the nullFilter example provided in the Microsoft minifilter samples. Managed to get a minimalist example working, so I am going to start from here. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Good luck and post again if you are in trouble. Also don't forget about OSR. There all the driver experts hang out.