# Minifilter Driver - CMD can still delete a file

Tags: c, command-line, minifilter

I'm trying to block access to a file (C:\pass\secret.txt) with a minifilter.

When I try to delete this file, I get the "Access Denied Msgbox" as expected.
But I can still delete the file with the "del" command from the command prompt.

What is the command prompt doing differently than the powershell, explorer or any other program I tried?

I saw this post [minifilter-driver-not-blocking-file-edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48466308/minifilter-driver-not-blocking-file-edition) but as I said, everything else is blocked.

The FltPreOperationCallback function:

```
FLT_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS PtPreOperationPassThrough(_Inout_ PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA Data, _In_ PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS FltObjects, _Flt_CompletionContext_Outptr_ PVOID *CompletionContext) {  

NTSTATUS status;

UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER( FltObjects );
UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER( CompletionContext );

if (PtDoRequestOperationStatus(Data)) {
    status = FltRequestOperationStatusCallback(Data, PtOperationStatusCallback, (PVOID)(++OperationStatusCtx));
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        PT_DBG_PRINT(PTDBG_TRACE_OPERATION_STATUS, ("PassThrough!PtPreOperationPassThrough: FltRequestOperationStatusCallback Failed, status=%08x\n", status));
    }
}

if (Data->Iopb->MajorFunction == IRP_MJ_WRITE || Data->Iopb->MajorFunction == IRP_MJ_SET_INFORMATION || Data->Iopb->MajorFunction == IRP_MJ_CREATE) {
    UNICODE_STRING ourFile;
    RtlInitUnicodeString(&ourFile, L"\\pass\\secret.txt");

    if (RtlCompareUnicodeString(&Data->Iopb->TargetFileObject->FileName, &ourFile, FALSE) == 0) {
        DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL, "PtPreOperationPassThrough: %wZ\n", &Data->Iopb->TargetFileObject->FileName);
        Data->IoStatus.Status = STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED;
        Data->IoStatus.Information = 0;
        return FLT_PREOP_COMPLETE;
    }
}

return FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_WITH_CALLBACK;
}
```

Comment: What filesystem is on drive C?

Comment: If you close all of those environments and try again after restarting each of them, does the difference persist?

Comment: @stark It's NTFS (Windows 10 x64 Pro)

Comment: @Yunnosch Yes. I even tried own C++ apps to delete this file and it's blocked.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you check for the FILE_DELETE_ON_CLOSE flag being set in the Create path.